# AWS IAM: Credential report via CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I'm trying to pull the credential report using AWS CLI as shown in [Getting Credential Reports for Your AWS Account - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html#getting-credential-reports-cliapi).

However, on doing so:

[image: Snapshot of my console]

I get a file like this and not the credential report.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The documentation page you linked says:

> **Content** -> (blob)
>
> Contains the credential report. The report is **Base64-encoded**.

From [GitHub: Get IAM Credential Report](https://gist.github.com/understeer/59063ca1bc1d82505413):

```
aws iam generate-credential-report
aws iam get-credential-report --output text --query Content  | base64 -D
```

Comment: Any tips how to do this in Windows cmd?

Comment: Nope. You could probably use some PowerShell to decode the base64.

Comment: Exact command is :

`aws iam get-credential-report --output text --query Content  | base64 -d`

with d minus :)